# JQuery Table Sorter plugin styling

Tags: c#, tablesorter

I implemented the table sorter yesterday and i have a problem trying to change the color of cells if a certain time is less then the current time i want to change the cells red if they fail this is my C# Code we originally just had a gridView which worked fine but we wanted to change it to make it faster for sorting heres the c# Code

```
 protected void gvResult_rowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime AppointmentTime = DateTime.Now;

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                AppointmentTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AppointmentTime"));

                if (AppointmentTime < DateTime.Now)
                {

                    e.Row.CssClass = "gvRowRed";
                    e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[3].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[4].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[5].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[6].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[7].CssClass = "white";
                }
                else if (AppointmentTime > DateTime.Now && AppointmentTime < DateTime.Now.AddHours(1))
                {
                    e.Row.CssClass = "gvRowGreen";
                    e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[3].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[4].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[5].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[6].CssClass = "white";
                    e.Row.Cells[7].CssClass = "white";
                }
            }


       }
```

Its the first part im concentrating on at the moment so if appointmenttime is less then datetime.now i need to color the cells background red and the color of the font white but for some reason thebackground color doesnt change, only the color of the font does any help would be appreciated.

Heres the CSS

```
table.tablesorter {
    font-family:arial;
    background-color: #CDCDCD;
    margin:10px 0pt 15px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #336699;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font:verdana;
    color:White;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url('/img/bg/bg.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter tbody td {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
    background-color:#F0F0F6;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url('/img/bg/asc.gif') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url('/img/bg/desc.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
background-color: #8dbdd8;
}

.gvRowRed
{
    background-color:Red !important;
}

.white
{
color:#ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant css too?

Comment: Please see the CSS above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
.gvRowRed
{
    background-color:Red !important;
}
```

to

```
.gvRowRed td
{
    background-color:Red !important;
}
```

and the same for gvRowGreen - it's applying the class to the row rather than the cell.